# How many even factors of $N =216\cdot15^6\cdot63^4$ are not factors of $M=14^8\cdot10^4\cdot3^5?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I find out number of even factors of $N$ (i.e. $1890$) and M (i.e. $3240$)
From here i am not able to proceed further.  How should i separate even factors of $N$ that are not factors of $M$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: I condensed the title of your post.  Please check that I didn't accidentally change the meaning.

Comment: As a first step, write $M$ and $N$ in their prime decompositions

Comment: Next, count how many even factors $M$ and $N$ have, and you can count how many of those even factors of $N$ are also factors of $M$.  Finally, subtract the bad from the total to get the good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$N=2^3\cdot3^{17}\cdot5^6\cdot7^4$$
$$M=2^{12}\cdot3^5\cdot5^4\cdot7^8$$

For a factor $f$ of $N$ to be a factor of $M$, no prime in the prime decomposition of $f$ can occur to a higher power than its power in the prime decomposition of $M$.  Thus, we want the number of even factors of $$N'=2^3\cdot3^5\cdot5^4\cdot7^4$$

This is $$3\cdot6\cdot5\cdot5=450$$

To put it in less convoluted terms, an even factor of $N$ that divides $M$ must be of the form $2^a\cdot3^b\cdot5^c\cdot7^d$ with $$1\leq a\leq3,\\0\leq b\leq5,\\0\leq c\leq4,\\0\leq d\leq4$$

Comment: @Levent $216=6^3=2^3\cdot3^3$  Where are the other factors of $2$ coming from?

Comment: Oh man, why did I think $216=2^8$. Sorry :)